# Easiest way to open a bank account in Canada as a US citizen

Tags: canada, bank-account

I need to open a checking account in Canada to transfer money between another Canadian bank account and I am wondering what is the easiest way to open a bank account in Canada as a US citizen without actually traveling to Canada. Preferably all online if possible.

Comment: Why do you need to transfer the funds if they're staying in Canada, and why can't you transfer them to where they're supposed to be going directly rather than needing another account? What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Probably because Canadian banks have easy, cheap person-to-person transfers and US banks do not.